# why ${C^n} = C({A^*}) \oplus N(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}(C)$.Is this true that ${C^n} = C({A^*}) \oplus N(A)$?(where $C(B)$ is column space and $N(B)$ is null space of $B$)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In fact, most linear algebra textbooks will have a proof that
$$
C(A^*) = N(A)^\perp
$$